# How to use a custom No Internet Connection Available layout when user is offline?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have been trying to use a custom Image that is to be shown to a user when he is offline and when the user clicks on the image, the activity should be reloaded.

P.s I am using Blogger API

Comment: need to make a common xml layout file for no internet connection and include in all activity's xml so you can easily handle click event to check is internet availble or not that's it.

Answer (score 1):

first add this permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

thin in your activty

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

and use like this

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
//internt connect
}else{
// no network 
//you can show image here by adding layout and set visibility gone and when no connection set visible
}
```

Comment: How to refresh the activity when the user clicks on the image?

Comment: you can set on click on image again this code
  `  if(isNetworkAvailable()){
    //internt connect
    }else{
   // no network 
   //you can show image here by adding layout and set visibility gone and when 
   no connection set visible
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Dialog of full Screen to check for internet. So, you can write,

```
if(isNetworkAvailable()){
        //Your Logic for Internet Connection
 }else {
    val noInternetDialog = Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme)
    noInternetDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    noInternetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.no_internet_layout)
    val window = noInternetDialog.window
    window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
    // What ever you have widget, can use them here.
    //for example
    val button_try_again = noInternetDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonId)
    val image_to_display = noInternetDialog.findViewById(R.id.imageId)
    // listeners for image

    noInternetDialog.show
 }
```

isNetworkAvaibale() is,

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {

        val connectivityManager = ApplicationInit.getAppContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
    }
```

PS : Do not forget to add Internet Permissions