# TWA - Struggling w/ Offline Screen implementation

Tags: java, android, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps, trusted-web-activity

This is my first Android project using Java and XML. (Which has been a process)

I'm having problems extending my `LauncherActivity` to display an Offline-Screen

I have been following [Offline-First Trusted Web Activities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/trusted-web-activity/offline-first/#create-a-custom-launcheractivity)

When this didn't work I followed some other Stackoverflows [Taking users to offline activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648775/take-user-to-offline-activity-screen-when-no-internet-connection-in-android-stud) |  [No internet Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070623/how-to-use-a-custom-no-internet-connection-available-layout-when-user-is-offline)

I noticed the key elements for this to work.

1. adding `user network perms to Mani fest.`
2. calling the new `offline activity` extend the `Launcher Activity` | *`Java file`*.
3. registering `offline activity in the Mani fest.`
4. Error handling | *`Java file`*
5. adding helpers `ConnectivityManager` / rendering `Layout activity` | *`Java file & XML`*

when I run the build - I still get the Dinosaur.

I used the code demo from - Chrome Dev as referenced above and followed up by using code from
[Offline First Demo](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/twa-offline-first)

Comment: this has been solved